# How to have notification with chat turned off on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there a way to have chat turned off (in order to be seen as logged out), but receive sound notifications when someone writes a message?

Answer (score 1):

**No**. There is no way to get sound notification if you have turned off chat.